# Is there an in-memory compressed swap facility (like Compcache) for FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, swap, compression

Is there anything like [CompCache](http://code.google.com/p/compcache/wiki/zramperf) for FreeBSD?

Comment: `CompCache` is like mfs or tmpfs in FreeBSD. You can turn on compression on FS level or use something like geom_uzip(4)

Answer (score 3):

```
# mdconfig -a -t malloc -o compress -o reserve -s 512m -u 7
# newfs -U /dev/md7
# mount /dev/md7 /mnt/ramdrive
```

Comment: albeit this might answer the quuestion can you elaborate a bit on the commands you suggested and what (specially the first line) do?

Comment: FreeBSD has special `md` driver that allow to create virtual drives with various backends, like file on the disk or part of RAM. `mdconfig` just create such virtual drive. `-t malloc` define that drive is placed in the RAM, `-o compress` define that this drive will be un/compressed on the fly, `-o reserve` means that all amount of RAM will be reserved at creation. After that command new device will be created in the `/dev` - `/dev/md7`. Then you can use it like any other device - until system reboot or manual destruction of virtual drive.

Comment: @Kondybas That's a compressed RAMdisk. The OP was asking for compressed swap. This is therefore more or less the opposite of what they were asking for.